# Convert Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object to an array and convert again to object

Tags: magento-1.8, array, object

I had encrypted customer's firstname ,lastname and email and need to decrypt data to show in front end.
I will be Overriding `public function getCustomer()` located at `app/code/core/Mage/Model/Session.php` file. 
Customer Data retrieved from 
`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    $customer->load($this->getId());`

**UPDATE**

When ever i use `print_r($customer)` to print data of logged in customer i get `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object`.

**Problem**

I want to replace decrypted value of firstname,lastname and email with an array `$customer['_origData:protected']` and `$customer['_Data:protected']`
since methods are protected so i have converted object into an array and converted again   into an Object after passing decryption function , but converted Object is without protected methods.
I'm getting Fatal Error when converted Object is passed to function  `$this->setCustomer($customer);`

**What I want** 
Replace three encrypted values  firstname , lastname and email in Object `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object`

**Basic Question is :-** How to Replace values in an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setData($key, $value)`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Object/Varien_Object.html#setData) to change `_data` and [`setOrigData($key, $value)`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Object/Varien_Object.html#setOrigData) to change `_origData`.

Also, instead of `setData('firstname', 'John')` you can always write `setFirstname('John')`, even though the method is not declared, thanks to the "magic" getters and setters in `Varien_Object`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand your question, but if you want to convert an array to a stdClass instance here is a simple way to do it.

```
$arr = YOUR ARRAY HERE;
$encoded = json_encode($arr);
$obj = json_decode($encoded);
```

Comment: I have encrypted data of customer and stored data into database. While editing information i get encrypted data so need to show decrypted means original.
`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
   print_r($customer);
        if ($this->getId()) {`
Above coding returns me stdClass object as
`[firstname] => XPPFukjwBbgUivv0MbvKN6SXB98VTRK1 [lastname] => 6Iyu6a4RZcE+m4CjwT99wQ`
so i want to decrypt data and again convert it into object by passing `$this->setCustomer($customer);`